# Data takes a long time to load

Tags: c#, azure, vue.js, ssms

I have a Maui net application for the mobile part and Vuejs for the web part, all of this is linked to an API in C#, and the database (SSMS) and the API are on Azure. The problem is that when I retrieve the data to display it it takes time (around 2-3 minutes). I don't know how to make it faster.

Vue.js

```
 async fetchActivities() {
    try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/v1/Activities/all');
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Network response was not ok, status: ${response.status}`);
    }
```

C#

```
 httpclient.BaseAddress = new Uri(AppSettings.UrlApi);
 httpclient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
 string oauthToken = await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync(AppSettings.AuthToken);
 httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", oauthToken);
 int loginUserId = Convert.ToInt32(await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync(AppSettings.UserId));
 var requestUri = "api/v1/Activities/all";

 var response = await httpclient.GetAsync(requestUri);
 var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Api

```
//[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class ActivitiesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IActivitiesRepository _activitiesRepository;
    private readonly IMessagesRepository _messagesRepository;
    private readonly IUsersRepository _usersRepository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IImagesRepository _imagesRepository;

    public ActivitiesController(IActivitiesRepository activitiesRepository, IMapper mapper, IUsersRepository usersRepository, IMessagesRepository messagesRepository, IImagesRepository imagesRepository)
    {
        _activitiesRepository = activitiesRepository;
        _usersRepository = usersRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _messagesRepository = messagesRepository;
        _imagesRepository = imagesRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ActivitiesEntity>> GetActivitiesbyIdAsync(int id)
    {
        ActivitiesEntity activitiesEntity = await _activitiesRepository.FindByIdAsync(id);
        return Ok(activitiesEntity);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("all")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ActivitiesEntity>>> GetActivities()
    {
        IEnumerable<ActivitiesEntity>? activities = await _activitiesRepository.FindAllIncludingAsync(x => x.Images);
        var response = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ActivitiesModel>>(activities);
        return Ok(response);
    }
```

```
 public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindAllIncludingAsync(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
 {
     IQueryable<TEntity> query = _entities.AsNoTracking();
     foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
     {
         query = query.Include(includeProperty);
     }
     return await query.ToListAsync();
 }
```

Comment: Are you querying images? If so, this will take a long time. Especially if there are any kind of joins or such. The first thing to optimize would be the query which grabs said data but that is not posted yet.

Comment: Indeed, each item recovered contains images, I didn't understand exactly what you want me to show

Comment: Show us your `FindAllIncludingAsync` method.

Comment: You should be using materialized `List<T>` collections of loaded data, not `IEnumerable<T>` types, because that can cause bugs like returning a Linq `IQueryable<T>` which won't be evaluated until after the request scope has been disposed...

Comment: I added the method, but I don't think that's what causes the bug because the loading is also long for the Web part which is with a different code

Comment: Use your profiler.

Comment: That is to say, can you elaborate?

Comment: Ideally yes use a profiler. If you can't do that, then as a simple first step try just putting a breakpoint on the first line of your `GetActivities` method. Step each line in turn and use tell us how many seconds each line takes. p.s. Not sure what you mean by "loading is also long for the Web part which is with a different code" - can you be specific and say which method you mean by "different code"? Thanks